# On perfect matches of $K_{m,m}$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math, matching-theory

> Alice has a collection of $2m-1$ different perfect matchings of
> $K_{m,m}$ ($\mathcal{M}_1,\mathcal{M}_2...\mathcal{M}_{2m-1}$). Prove
> that Alice can pick exactly one edge from each of
> $\mathcal{M}_{i_1},\mathcal{M}_{i_2},...\mathcal{M}_{i_m}$ for some
> $\{i_1,i_2,...i_m\}\subset\{1,2,...,2m-1\}$ such that the picked edges
> form themselves a perfect matching of $K_{m,m}$.

Note: $K_{m,m}$ is the complete bipartite set with $m$ vertices on each side and a perfect matching is a set of edges such that each vertex has degree $1$.

---

I thought myself and My main idea was to look at subgraphs of $K_{m,m}$, $K_{n,n}$ such that for each $i$, $\mathcal{M}_i$ forms a perfect matching for $K_{n,n}$ and induction  would finish the job.

I also thought that interpreting edges as lattice points, but this didn't work.

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is named a "rainbow matching", and its existence is proved in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0097316598928941

EDIT : the exact link between these results may not be clear, so check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_matching for a more direct explanation :)

Comment: Oh, that's great. Thanks for clearing it up! :)